# Apply Map Reduce in Java

Tags: java, mapreduce, set, tuples, java-stream

I am very much a beginner to streams, `map`, `reduce`, and `filter`.

I am getting a List of rows from my Cassandra table which contains three fields `vehicleType`, `noOfVehicles` and `taxPerParticularVehicleType`.

I want to prepare a set of triplets of these 3 such that the no of vehicles of any particular type should be added while the triple should also contain the arithmetic mean of the tax for a particular vehicle type.

I am applying my mapping such as :

```
session.execute(statement).all().stream()
            .map(row -> new ImmutablePair<>(row.getString("vehicleType"), new ImmutablePair<>(row.getInt("noOfVehicles"), row.getFloat("tollTaxOfParticularType") * row.getInt("noOfVehicles"))))
            .reduce(x->{

            });
```

and I am unable to apply the reduce such that it should be added to following set:

```
Set<Triple<String,Integer,Double>> set = new HashSet<>();
```

I am giving an example of what I want to achieve through Map-Reduce :

I am mapping three fields (vehicleType,noOfVehicle,taxOfParticularVehicle) coming from my table such as :

```
(vehicleType,(noOfVehicle,noOfVehicle*taxOfParticularVehicle))
```

Suppose the mapping gives me an array like this :

```
[("A",(12,48)),("A",(10,30)),("B",(3,30)),("B",(4,70))]
```

In the end I want to reduce it to following set:

```
[("A",22,39),("B",7,50)]
```

such that noOfVehicles are getting summed up while the tax is the arithmetic mean of the vehicle taxes in the group.

Comment: yeah you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky without streaming more than once or maintaining mutable state externally. The cleanest alternative to those approaches appears to be to write a custom `Collector`.

I'm not very comfortable with `Pair`, `Triple` and what not, so I'm using concrete classes for the sake of illustration:
`Data` is a holder for an individual data point and corresponds to your triple of data.

```
static final class Data {
    final String type;
    final int noOfVehicles;
    final double totalTax;
    Data(String type, int noOfVehicles, double totalTax) {
        this.type = type;
        this.noOfVehicles = noOfVehicles;
        this.totalTax = totalTax;
    }
}
```

Next, we need a helper class that holds the state during the mutable reduction, I'll call this `Stats`:

```
static final class Stats {
    int noOfVehiclesSum;
    double totalTaxSum;
    int count;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stats{" + "noOfVehiclesSum=" + noOfVehiclesSum +
               ", averageTax=" + (totalTaxSum / count) + '}';
    }
}
```

Let's create a list of test data

```
List<Data> l = Arrays.asList(new Data("A", 12, 48.0),
                             new Data("A", 10, 30.0),
                             new Data("B", 3 , 30.0),
                             new Data("B", 4 , 70.0),
                             new Data("B", 5 , 20.0));
```

What I want as a final result of the reduction is a `Map<String, Stats>` that contains the mapping from the vehicleType to the `Stats` object for that type (containing the sum of vehicle counts and the tax average for that type).

In this example: `{A=Stats{noOfVehiclesSum=22, averageTax=39.0}, B=Stats{noOfVehiclesSum=12, averageTax=40.0}}`

I don't know of a better solution than to write your own customized `Collector` which, in this example, looks somewhat like the following:

```
static class StatsCollector implements Collector<Data, Stats, Stats> {
    @Override
    public Supplier<Stats> supplier() {
        return Stats::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Stats, Data> accumulator() {
        return (stats, data) -> {
            stats.noOfVehiclesSum += data.noOfVehicles;
            stats.totalTaxSum += data.totalTax;
            stats.count += 1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Stats> combiner() {
        return (lft, rght) -> {
            lft.noOfVehiclesSum += rght.noOfVehiclesSum;
            lft.totalTaxSum += rght.totalTaxSum;
            lft.count += rght.count;
            return lft;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Stats, Stats> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.of(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);
    }
}
```

Finally, after all this plumbing, you'll be able to write

```
Map<String, Stats> result = l.stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(data -> data.type,
                                                            new StatsCollector()));
```

and get the desired mapping.

Comment: yeah,i could do this but i want to group them on such basis that particular vechile type numbers should be collected that they are sumed up

Comment: @Dhiresh Budhiraja Could you add a spec or example to your question so that we can understand what *exactly* you want to achieve?

Comment: I have given the example now,could you help me further